# (SOLVED) Python runs code in VS Code that does not exist

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-cache

Solution: The Login form automatically opens when not logged in to chrome or the website itself. No need to worry about this ;)

Here is the problem I had:

I have the following problem: I want to write a Python code that uses the Selenium webdriver to go to tiktok.com and click on the login button. I have made some changes to the code because some things were not working as intended. The problem now is that every time I go to tiktok.com with the driver, it clicks on the login button, even though I have deleted those lines of code. Even if I only put in:
`from selenium import webdriver driver = webdriver.Chrome() driver.get(https://www.tiktok.com/)`
it clicks on the button without me telling it to do so. The strange thing is that it first executes the old code (which doesn't exist anymore) and as soon as I manually make any changes on the website (e.g. accept cookies or click away the test software notice), it executes the code that I actually want to use and have shared below. Is it possible that VS Code has cached the code somewhere, associated with my code file, so that when I press execute, it first executes the old code, then stops and waits for another action before continuing? If so, how can I delete this? For your information: The code below currently works and is not cached anywhere, so that if I change the button there (I have taken the settings button instead of the login button for testing purposes), it will no longer be executed when accessing the website. I have also cleared the cookies etc. in the Chrome browser. However, the problem persists even if I use Edge instead of Chrome.
I also tried:
Use Webbrowser instead of Webdriver(It still executes the old code), change website(e.g. if i access microsoft.com it does not execute the old code)

Here is the Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/")

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "header-more-menu-icon"))
)
button.click()

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Yes, I saved the file.

Comment: Ok. I want you to go to notepad, and open this file with the code. See if it's still the old version

Comment: When opened in notepad it shows me the correct version (The one i have put into my stackoverflow question at the end)

Comment: Huh... ok. Sorry, it's a bit late in my timezone, so I'll need a break. But try use `python "insert-filename"` in the terminal. That should work.

Comment: The file is simply named "Webdriver". When I type in python "Webdriver" it tells me that there is no such file or directory so i gave him the whole path and typed in "python "D:\Python\Webdriver.py"" because thats where the file is saved. Then it runs the code but still with the existing issue.

Comment: Solved it. Well uhm... I copied the file to C:\ and deleted the one in D:\.  Somehow the copied version worked. Then I moved this copy back to my python folder on D:\ and it still works. This makes absolutely no sense but if it works it works haha. Thanks for your time and help :D

Comment: I've been thinking some more about why it works this way now and have a theory that makes sense. When you are logged in to Chrome via Google, the login window doesn't open automatically. If you are not logged in it opens automatically. Since I had accessed the website myself while logged in, I didn't know this. However, the chrome webdriver in the Python file opens the page in the logged out state. Therefore the login window opens automatically.

Comment: My code starts and opens the page as it should, but then stops at the button, waiting for it to appear. Since the login form pops up automatically by tiktok, it does not find it. If I close it manually the presence of the button is set to true and the code continues.

Comment: minimize the question post so it contains only what is needed to reproduce and understand the core problem. Then write up an answer post (see [answer]) :)

Comment: Well eitherways, good to hear! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Login form automatically opens when not logged in to chrome or the website itself. No need to worry about this ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).